# Using Travis-CI to test Homebrew tap

Tags: homebrew, travis-ci

I've just discovered Travis-CI, and it seems very useful for testing whether Homebrew formulae build correctly on different systems, especially since Homebrew is already installed on their VMs. In short, I have a Homebrew tap and would like to use Travis-CI to test the formulae on different systems.

The way I see this working would be to have a test script something like:

```
brew update
brew tap <my/tap>
brew install <package>
brew test <package>
```

But some problems I could see arising are:

- what would be the language in this case? I'm letting Homebrew deal with the build
- Travis-CI only seems to allow a single test script per repository, so it would be difficult to separate the testing of each formula

Can anyone help with some advice about these two points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

fYou need to use `objective-c` as the language to get an OS X VM.  This is admittedly not very obvious.

To build multiple packages, you can use an environment variable matrix.  (Or you could write a shell script with a big loop over all packages.)

Here is a `.travis.yml` template you can use:

```
language: objective-c
before_install:
  - brew update
install:
  - mkdir -p $(brew --repo)/Library/Taps/travis
  - ln -s $PWD $(brew --repo)/Library/Taps/travis/homebrew-testtap
  - brew tap --repair
env:
  - PACKAGE=first_package
  - PACKAGE=second_package
  ...
script:
  - brew audit $PACKAGE
  - brew install -v $PACKAGE
  - brew test $PACKAGE
```

Comment: Thanks for this question, by the way.  I just took your idea and implemented it for my own tap, like I show above.

Comment: Thanks so much! This really seems that there's a lot of potential here. I might add a commit-hook that lists all my formulae in the YAML file.

Comment: Thanks for the question - exactly what I was looking for! Do you have the commit-hook yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, this template doesn't seem to work anymore. It's really hard to find info on this. I'm struggling with https://travis-ci.org/gemnasium/homebrew-gemnasium/builds/143206722 currently

Comment: @Gravis: I have updated the `install` section for a change in the directory layout.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut: Awesome! You made my day :)